# how can I display a secret word in a "label" in c# by pressing a "submit button" in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int ranNum;
    Random ranNumGen;
    string[] words;
    const int post = 20;

    public Form1()
    {
        words = new string[post];
        ranNumGen = new Random();
        words = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\prog\c\c\text.txt");
    }

    //Start new game 
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*here what i want is that when button1 is pressed the game would start */
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* here in label 1 what i want is random word from a text file to be displayed in a manner that it could be guessed*/
    }

    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* here this is a "submit" button, a word in a text box is submitted and compared to random word from the text file */
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /* in this text box the user enters a word, and the word has to match the random word from the text file*/
    }
}
```

}

What i want is to create a "guess the word game" 
the user types in a word in a text box, and when submit button is pressed
the word submitted will be compared to the random word from a text file, if both words match the game is won. tks

Comment: Huh? Do you mean display asterisks instead of the actual word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to do in those handlers ?

**EDIT** So you want to get a random word from a file and want to display in a label ?

TO do this you can use:

`var word = File.ReadAllLines(@"Location");`

`answer = word[new Random().Next(word.Length)];`

Comment: @Ryan how can i used dose 2 lines of code and in which "private void shall I place them

Comment: Depends where you want the word to appear. If when pressing button 1 then inside that handler.

Comment: First display the whole word. To display only parts of it is another task.